# Send picklist value to Dynamics crm online to create lead using soap php

Tags: php, api, soap, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to create a lead in crm 365 online using soap in php. I can create a lead successfully by sending soap request but I want to send leadsource as well and it's a picklist in crm. Here is my code in php. Not sure which datatype to use, int32 or picklist, but both are not working.

```
<b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>leadsourcecode</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:OptionSetValue" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">100000010</c:value>
        </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>';
```

I am getting this error:

```
Sendera:DeserializationFailedThe formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:entity. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 22 position 82. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:OptionSetValue'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'OptionSetValue' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'. Please see InnerException for more details.
```

Comment: What error are you receiving? OptionSetValue is the way you would normally set a picklist value

Comment: I have edited the question for error i am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a **capital V** for the inner value tag. Here is code that works that I use to update the status reason, modify as appropriate. Also, the SOAP endpoint is deprecated, you should move to the WebAPI

```
request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
request += "<c:key>Status</c:key>";
request += "<c:value i:type=\"a:OptionSetValue\">";
request += "<a:Value>" + 2 + "</a:Value>";
request += "</c:value>";
request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
<a:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
 <b:key>leadsourcecode</b:key>
 <b:value i:type="a:OptionSetValue">
  <a:value>100000010</a:value>
 </b:value>
</a:keyvaluepairofstringanytype>
```

Comment: I tried above code but it is still not working. No error, it creates a lead but without leadsourcecode. pls suggest